# Correct way to do U-sub

Tags: integration, solution-verification

Consider the following problem. $$\int x^2\sin (x^3) dx$$ let $u=x^3$ so $du=3x^2 dx$.Then, $$\int x^2\sin (u) \frac{du}{3x^2}=\frac{1}{3}\int \sin(u)du$$
Is it mathematically correct? My concern is about keeping two variables $x$ and $u$ inside the integral sing. I know it can be done as follows:
$$\int x^2\sin (x^3) dx=\frac{1}{3}\int 3x^2\sin (x^3) dx$$  and then let $u=x^3$ and $du=3x^2 dx.$ The point beyond my question is to know the correct way to teach someone the right way to do u-sub. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: It is OK to keep both variables inside the integral sign. $\int x^2dx = \int x y dx$, if I define $y:=x$

Answer (score 10):

I'd instead rewrite it as $\frac13du=x^2\,dx,$ so that $$\int x^2\sin\left(x^3\right)\,dx=\int\sin\left(x^3\right)x^2\,dx=\int\sin(u)\cdot\frac13\,du=\frac13\int\sin(u)\,du.$$ That way, we never divide by something that can be equal to $0.$

Comment: Many students in second-semester calculus still do that whole "mix-and-match", perhaps because they were taught that way. I always tell students to "match as best you can," and not juggle two variables inside the integrand. This way is my preferred method.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to realize the proposed substitution:
\begin{align*}
\int x^{2}\sin(x^{3})\mathrm{d}x & = \frac{1}{3}\int 3x^{2}\sin(x^{3})\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = \frac{1}{3}\int\sin(x^{3})\mathrm{d}(x^{3})\\\\
& = \frac{1}{3}\int\sin(u)\mathrm{d}u
\end{align*}

which is easy to integrate.

Hopefully this helps!